# Can I switch from the target branch to master locally without changing the content of the local repository?

Tags: git, gitlab, branch

I've just merged a target branch to master and everything is OK in the remote repository. Can I switch from the target branch to master locally without losing any untracked file in the local repository (and, in general, without changing the content of the local repository)? If I run "git checkout master", I can see a lot of old files that are not in the remote repository.

Answer (score 0):

When you checkout any branch you don't lose your untracked files. Checkout operation it's just building your working directory content (Working directory is folder there where you have .git folder) from every commit on checkouted branch.

Maybe the better question is, why you want switch to branch without checkouted files? I dont know any way to do operation like this. But also it's first time when i see that someone want do operation like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can [stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) any non-commited changes in you current branch, before checking out master. This helps ensure when you open master that none of those files have modifications.

If you want to get your changes back and apply them to either master or that other branch you can unstash.

**However**, if you are wanting to check out master but also keep the files you have floating around locally (perhaps if you plan to check them in eventually), you should be able to perform a checkout of master, and barring any merge conflicts, keep any uncommitted changes locally.